# Apply multiple whereNotEqualTo() to ParseQuery

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
ParseQuery<User> searchUserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(User.class);
searchUserQuery.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
searchUserQuery.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", "some object id");
```

I am getting current user in my result. Which means only the second `whereNotEqualTo()` is applied to the query. May I know how to apply multiple `whereNotEqualTo()` to a ParseQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Array of String of `users` `ObjectId`

```
String[] listObjectId= {"objectId1", "objectId2", "objectId3"};
query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", Arrays.asList(listObjectId));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It doesn't work, I need to query for ParseUser rows where objectId column is not equal to "objectId1", "objectId2", "objectId3", ParseUser objectId column is not array type